# Why the following code is not working over actual server but it's working fine over localhost?

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am using Maatwebsite/Excel package to export .csv file. My code is running well over localhost but when i am trying to run it over actual server it's not working and showing

> local.INFO: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
>   on line no. 62

At localhost, when I am exporting a generated report, it get store at public/reports and also email is going to user. But when I ran the code on server, its giving the error

It's Controller function :

```
try {
            $report = 'Appointment_' . Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString() . '_Report.csv';
            $report_path = 'reports/Appointment_' . Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString() . '_Report.csv';
//            Log::info(var_dump($data));
            $created = Excel::store($data, $report, 'reports');
            $user_id = $request->session()->get('user_id');
            app('App\Http\Controllers\API\AppointmentController')->sendDocument($report_path, config('constants.DOCUMENT_TYPE.REP'), $user_id);

            if($created) {
                echo json_encode(array('type' => 'success', 'message' => 'Report Exported successfully'));
            }
```

It's collection code in Exports :

```
public function collection()
    {
        $data = Session::get('report_query');
//        Log::info($data);
        $d = DB::select($data);
        return collect($d);
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        $field = Session::get('fields');
        foreach ($field as $f) {
            $arr[] = config("constants.REPORTS_FIELDS." . str_replace('.', '_', $f));
        }
            return $arr;
//        return array_keys($this->collection()->toArray()[0]);
        }
```

Comment: post the full error

Comment: [2019-04-10 10:22:12] local.INFO: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array givenon line no. 62 .